# Show that $J_0(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(x+y\right)}{x+y}J_0(y)dy$

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form, bessel-functions

I've been trying to show, without success, that:
\begin{align*}
J_0(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\left(x+y\right)}{x+y}J_0(y)dy\quad\text{for }0\leq x<\infty,
\end{align*}
where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $0$. The result has been verified numerically.

One of the things I tried is to use the integral representation $\frac{1}{x+y}=\int_0^\infty e^{-t(x+y)}dt$ an apply Fubini's. After simplying the first integral I arrive at:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{i\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\left(\frac{\cos x+i\sin x}{\sqrt{(t-i)^2+1}}+\frac{-\cos x+i\sin x}{\sqrt{(t+i)^2+1}}\right)dt,
\end{align*}
which I doubt has a simple closed-form.

Comment: +1. Looking forward to seeing how this one develops. Another appearance of the $\operatorname{sinc}$ kernel.

Comment: +1 for this nice question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $I(x)$ be represented by the integral

$$\begin{align}
I(x)&=\frac2\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}J_0(y)\,dy\tag1
\end{align}$$

Letting $t=-x$ and $I(-t)=J(t)$ in $(1)$ we see that

$$\begin{align}
J(t)&=\frac2\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(t-\tau)}{t-\tau}J_0(\tau)H(\tau)\,d\tau\\\\
&=\frac2\pi (\text{sinc}*J_0H)(t)\tag2
\end{align}$$

Using the convolution theorem, the Fourier transform of $J(t)$ in $(2)$, as given by $\mathscr{F}\{J\}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty J(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt$, can be expressed as

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{J\}(\omega)&=\frac2\pi\underbrace{\mathscr{F}\{\text{sinc}\}(\omega)}_{=\pi \text{Rect}(\omega/2)}\mathscr{F}\{J_0H\}(\omega)\\\\
&=2\text{rect}(\omega/2)\int_0^\infty J_0(t) e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\\\
&=2\text{rect}(\omega/2) \left(\int_0^\infty J_0(t) \cos(\omega t)\,dt+i\int_0^\infty J_0(t) \sin(\omega t)\,dt\right)\\\\
&=2\text{rect}(\omega/2) \left(\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty J_0(t) e^{i\omega t}\,dt+i\int_0^\infty J_0(t) \sin(\omega t)\,dt\right)\tag3
\end{align}$$

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78316/fourier-transform-of-bessel-functions/1360271#1360271), I showed that the Fourier Transform of $J_0(t)$ is equal to $\mathscr{F}\{J_0\}(\omega)=\frac{2\text{rect}(\omega/2)}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}}$ while using the result found [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603506/integral-of-bessel-function-multiplied-with-sine-int-0-infty-j-0bx-sinax/1829730#1829730), we see that $\int_0^\infty J_0(t)\sin(\omega t)\,dt=0$ when $|\omega|<1$.

Using these results in $(3)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{J\}(\omega)&= \frac{2\text{rect}(\omega/2)}{\sqrt{1-\omega^2}}\tag4
\end{align}$$

Since the inverse Fourier Transform of the right-hand side of $(4)$ is $J_0(t)$ and $J_0(t)=J_0(-t)=J_0(x)$, we are done!.

Comment: How did we conclude that:
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{F}\{J_0H\}(\omega)=\frac1{2\pi}\left(\mathscr{F}\{J_0\}*\mathscr{F}\{H\}\right)(\omega)?
\end{align*}

Comment: We appealed to the convolution theorem again.

Comment: @AndrésSantos I've edited the answer to streamline the analysis, which now avoids the second application of the convolution theorem.

Comment: Excellent, the argument seems to be more clear. We may also evaluate
\begin{align*}
\int_0^\infty J_0\left(t\right)e^{i\omega t}dt
\end{align*}
directly by using the integral representation
\begin{align*}
J_0\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\cos\left(x\sin\theta\right)d\theta,\qquad \text{Re }x>0.
\end{align*}
Which is shown [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326778/laplace-transform-of-the-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind).

Comment: Yes, I believe I covered that.

Answer (score 1):

If we integrate over the entire real line, we get the peculiar result $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} \, J_{0}(y) \, \mathrm dy = \pi J_{0}(x) =2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} \, J_{0}(y) \, \mathrm dy. $$

It's peculiar because the integrand is not even.

---

More generally, we can show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} \, J_{n}(y) \, \mathrm dy= \pi (-1)^{n}  J_{n}(x) $$ for $x \ge 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$.

Consider the  function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{i(x+z)}}{x+z} \, J_{n}(z). $$

For $0 < \arg(z) < \pi$,  $$|f(z)| \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \,  \frac{1}{|z|^{3/2}}$$ as $|z| \to \infty$.  (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms).)

Therefore, if we integrate counterclockwise around a contour consisting of the real axis (indented at $z=-x$) and the semicircle above it, it follows from the estimation lemma that $$\operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i(x+y)}}{x+y} \, J_{n}(y) \, \mathrm dy - i \pi \operatorname{Res}[f(z), -x] =0, $$

where $$\operatorname{Res}[f(z), -x] = e^{i(x-x)} J_{n}(-x) = (-1)^{n} J_{n}(x). $$

Equating the imaginary parts on both sides of the equation, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} \, J_{n}(y) \, \mathrm dy = \pi (-1)^{n}J_{n}(x).  $$